# Why is NLP and Machine Learning community interested in deep learning?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, neural-network, deep-learning

Why is there a lot of interest in the NLP and ML community for deep learning?
Why do they need approaches to learn complex non-linear relationships?

Comment: You might get better answers on http://datascience.stackexchange.com/. StackOverflow isn't really intended for this type of question.

Comment: belongs to http://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks, I didnt know that site. So I asked this question with more information there: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/1253/why-is-there-a-lot-of-interest-in-the-nlp-and-machine-learning-community-for-dee

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the most interesteing things about deep learning is the capability of in an unsupervised way you can learn high level features.

Comment: can you please answer this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69107390/implication-of-deep-learning-model-on-nlp-tabular-data

Answer (score 3):

Deep learning neural networks have recently have shown [very powerful improvements in tasks in computer vision and NLP](http://www.nytimes.com/2012/11/24/science/scientists-see-advances-in-deep-learning-a-part-of-artificial-intelligence.html?pagewanted=all&_r=0) compared to some other machine learning methods that have been popular for longer.

At least in acoustic modelling for speech recognition, deep learning helps us get better features when compared to [MFCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mel-frequency_cepstrum)s.

Answer (score 0):

For an in depth look at deep learning and why it is important and interesting, take a look at my article here http://simonwinder.com/2015/01/what-is-deep-learning/ I have been working on this stuff since the 90s and its bizarre to see it take off so suddenly.

Comment: can you please look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69107390/implication-of-deep-learning-model-on-nlp-tabular-data